# CSS - align lines by character

Tags: html, css

I have a page like this:

[page http://ompldr.org/vZTJtdw](http://ompldr.org/vZTJtdw)

I need to align the lines by the '>' character. I think this can be done using a table, but I guess there is some better solution?

What I have so far: https://gist.github.com/2864265

Comment: And this looked so promising, once: [CSS alignment-by-character](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#character-alignment).

Comment: @DavidThomas the feature is at risk and might be dropped from the spec, because there is no interoperable implementations of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table. Align the left column to the right, so that it is aligned by the rightmost character.

Comment: I got it using a table. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
.title { display: inline-block; width: 2.8em;}
```

or use a table, which is more flexible (no need to make a guess on the width), more robust (works even when CSS is off or party unsupported), and more logical (what you have is a two-dimensional array of data).

I presume that by alignment you meant that you would like to have the GREATER THAN signs vertically on the same line.